# How can I form two arrays to one array object?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I am have two arrays $A(array of object) and $B

```
  $A = 
  Array
  (
  [0] => objval Object
      (

      [id_groupe] => 51
      )

  [1] => objval Object
      (

      [id_groupe] => 46
      )

  [2] => objval Object
      (
      [id_groupe] => 52
      )

  )


  $B = 
  Array(51,46)
```

I want to return new one , if it's `id_groupe` of `$A` exisiting in `$B` so it will be expected result like this:

```
  Array
  (

  [0] => objval Object
      (
      [id_groupe] => 52
      )

  )
```

Any could help me?

Comment: Actually that's just set minus operation, ain't it?

Comment: yes,the new of array object just remove the $A if ele of $A existing in $B

Comment: please look my update question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this will solve your problem:

```
// object class
class xy{

    public $id_groupe = 0;

    function xy($id_groupe){
        $this->id_groupe = $id_groupe;
    }


}

// initialize test case Array A
$A = array();
$A[] = new xy(51);
$A[] = new xy(46);
$A[] = new xy(52);

// initialize test case Array B
$B = array(46,51);

// init result array
$diff = array();

// Loop through all elements of the first array
foreach($A as $elem)
{
  // Loop through all elements of the second loop
  // If any matches to the current element are found,
  // they skip that element
  foreach($B as $elem2)
  {
    if($elem->id_groupe == $elem2) continue 2;
  }
  // If no matches were found, append it to $diff
  $diff[] = $elem;
}

// test Array
print_r($diff);
```

Comment: $A is array of object $B is an array.

Comment: $elem->id_groupe,BUT from you code I still get all elements of $A ?

Comment: yes,Thariama ,it works,Could you explain me  what "continue 2;" mean?

Comment: "continue 2" triggers "continue" not on the inner loop but the outer loop. using "continue 3" continue would be called in the outer-outer loop (if this exists)

Comment: @Thariama, Thanks,for your explanation.